# Predeclare search location for anticipated find_library()-call

Tags: cmake, libraries, static-linking

I want to include an external library as a subproject into my own project and link its target(s) statically against my own lib.

The said project somewhere in its CMake calls the following find-functions:

```
find_library(MBEDTLS_LIBRARY mbedtls)
find_library(MBEDX509_LIBRARY mbedx509)
find_library(MBEDCRYPTO_LIBRARY mbedcrypto)
```

The subproject expects mbedtls to already be installed somewhere on the system, but it didn't consider the fact that I want to link statically. My approach is to now `FetchContent` mbedtls and provide the find_library() calls with the prebuilt static libraries.

Now I need a way provide those find_library-calls with the right search directory, of course without modifying its source code. Can I somehow set a prefix path? I know I could probably set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH but that seems like an ugly hack and it would probably affect other find_library()-calls within the project which also exist. Is there a more "constrained" way?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes I tried `list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "${mbedtls_BINARY_DIR}/library/")`. Is this the right thing to do? In any case, it didn't work just now

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow set a prefix path?

Setting a prefix path won't help `find_library` to locate the library, because command `find_library` searches the **file** at **configuration** stage, but the library is built only on **build** stage.

Instead, you may **write** the **target name** to the CACHE variable, which is passed to `find_library` as the first argument:

- When find the result variable to be already set, `find_library` won't search the library file.
- In most cases a project uses result of `find_library` in the call to `target_link_libraries`, so having the library target in the result variable will fit to the project's expectations.

Example:

```
FetchContent_Declare(mbedtls ...)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(mbedtls)

set(MBEDTLS_LIBRARY MbedTLS::mbedtls CACHE INTERNAL "mbedtls library target")
```

With such setup the following

```
find_library(MBEDTLS_LIBRARY mbedtls)
```

will do nothing, since the variable `MBEDTLS_LIBRARY` is already set.

And if the project will use this variable like

```
target_link_libraries(<executable> ${MBEDTLS_LIBRARY})
```

then it effectively gets

```
target_link_libraries(<executable> MbedTLS::mbedtls)
```

---

Name of the target which should be assigned to the variable could sometime be found from the project's documentation, but otherwise you need to look into the project's sources (`CMakeLists.txt`).

E.g. in case of mbedtls project, the library target `mbedtls` is [created](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/blob/development/library/CMakeLists.txt#L295) with `add_library()` call, and `MbedTLS::mbedtls` is [created](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/blob/development/library/CMakeLists.txt#L301) as ALIAS for it.